# "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error" How can I solve it

Tags: java, sockets, http

I have a problem with my senior project. My objective is to read and modify HTTP response packet. I have a problem about `java.net.SocketException`. Could you help me, please?
Exception at Responsethread

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:147)
    at helper.ResponseThread.run(ResponseThread.java:163)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 4 minutes 3 seconds)
```

Here is my code

Helper.java

```java
package helper;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Helper {
    public void proc() {
        try {
            
            ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(80);
            String hostname="www.hungeng.besaba.com";
            InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
            //int serverPort=3456;
            //Socket clientSocket =new Socket(ip,serverPort);
           //String ipAddr="31.170.164.70"; //http://hungeng.besaba.com/

            while (true) {
              
                Socket sockC = servsock.accept();

                //get input stream of the Socket(sockC) from Client 
                InputStream inC = sockC.getInputStream();
                //get output stream of the Socket(sockC) to Client
                OutputStream outC = sockC.getOutputStream();

                //Connect to the specified server(ipAddr) at the 80 port. 
                Socket sockS = new Socket(ip, 80);

                //get input stream of the Socket(sockS) from server(ipAddr)
                InputStream inS = sockS.getInputStream();
                //get output stream of the Socket(sockS) to server(ipAddr)
                OutputStream outS = sockS.getOutputStream();

                //Create Thread for sending The Request Message from Client 
                RequestThread request = new RequestThread();
                //Create Thread for sending The Response Message to Client
                ResponseThread response = new ResponseThread();

                // match a Request Thread with a Response Thread
                request.server = response;
                response.client = request;
                request.is = inC;
                request.os = outC;
                response.is = inS;
                response.os = outS;
                
                request.start();
                response.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
         new Helper().proc();
    }
}
```

RequestThread.java

```java
package helper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class RequestThread extends Thread {
    InputStream is;
    OutputStream os;
    ResponseThread server;
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;

    public void run() {
        try {
           int i=0;
           
           while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) !=-1) {
               server.os.write(buf,0,bytesRead);
               server.os.flush();
            }
         
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ResponseThread.java

```java
package helper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ResponseThread extends Thread {
    int num;
    String content = "";
    InputStream is;
    OutputStream os;
    RequestThread client;
    byte[] buf = new byte[20000];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    String endMark = "\r\n\r\n";

    public void run() {
        try {
            String msg = "";

            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {

                msg += new String(buf, 0, bytesRead);
              //  System.out.println("message");
                //System.out.println(msg);
               // System.out.println("---------");
                //client.os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                int eHeader = msg.indexOf("\r\n\r\n");
                String header = msg.substring(0, eHeader + "\r\n\r\n".length());

                // System.out.println("header");
                //System.out.println(header);
                //System.out.println("-----------");
                int sConLength = header.indexOf("Content-Length: ");
                if (sConLength != -1) {
                    //have content length  
                    String temp = header.substring(sConLength);
                    int eConLength = temp.indexOf("\r\n");
                    int cl = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring("Content-Length: ".length(), eConLength));
                    String uConlen = header.substring(0, sConLength + "Content-Length: ".length());
                    System.out.println("uconlen ");
                    System.out.println(uConlen);
                    System.out.println("--------");

                    String lConlen = temp.substring(eConLength + "\r\n".length());
                    System.out.println("lconlen ");
                    System.out.println(lConlen);
                    System.out.println("-----------------");
                    int sHtml = msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("<html>");
                    int eHtml = msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("</html>");
                    if ((sHtml != -1) && (eHtml != -1)) {
                        //has Html content
                        System.out.println(":::Have Html content:::");
                        int sForm = msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("<form");
                        int eForm = msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("</form>");
                        if ((sForm != -1) && (eForm != -1)) {
                            //have form
                            System.out.println(":::Have form:::");
                            String form = msg.substring(sForm, eForm + "</form>".length());
                            String uForm = msg.substring(eHeader + "\r\n\r\n".length(), sForm);
                            String lForm = msg.substring(eForm + "</form>".length());
                            String p = "<p id=\"demo\"></p>";
                            String bt = "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"fill_in(name)\">Fill In</button>\n";
                            String[] data = {"Natta santawalim", "110033333333", "adressssss"};
                            String sc = "<script>\n ";
                            sc += "function fill_in(name) \n";
                            sc += "{\n";
                            sc += "document.getElementById(\"txtUsername\").value=\'";
                            sc += data[0];
                            sc += "\'; \n";
                            sc += "document.getElementById(\"txtPassword\").value=\'";
                            sc += data[1];
                            sc += "\'; \n";
                            sc += "document.getElementById(\"txtName\").value=\'";
                            sc += data[2];
                            sc += "\'; \n";
                            sc += "}\n";
                            sc += "</script>\n";

                            // client.os.write(result.getBytes());
                            cl += bt.length() + p.length() + sc.length();
                            client.os.write(uConlen.getBytes());
                            String l = Integer.toString(cl) + "\r\n";
                            client.os.write(l.getBytes());
                            client.os.write(lConlen.getBytes());
                            client.os.write(uForm.getBytes());
                            client.os.write(form.getBytes());
                            client.os.write(bt.getBytes());
                            client.os.write(sc.getBytes());
                            client.os.write(p.getBytes());
                            client.os.write(lForm.getBytes());

                            //                       System.out.println("byte "+);
                            //System.out.println("numofsent byr"+s);
                        } else {
                            //don't have form
                            System.out.println(":::Dont Have form:::");
                            //client.os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                            String packet = msg.substring(eHeader + "\r\n\r\n".length());
                            client.os.write(header.getBytes());
                            client.os.write(packet.getBytes());

                            client.os.flush();
                        }

                    } else {
                        // don't have Html content
                        System.out.println(":::Dont Have Html content:::");
                        client.os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                        //client.os.flush();
                        //  num+=bytesRead;
                        //System.out.println("num "+num);
                    }
                } else {
                    //don't have content length,transfer-encoding: chunk
                    System.out.println("chunk");
                    //client.os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    // System.out.println("message");
                    //System.out.println(msg);
                    int fChunk = header.indexOf("Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
                //    String m = msg.substring(eHeader + "\r\n\r\n".length());
                    if (fChunk != -1) {
                        //chunk

                        int sHtml = msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("<html>");
                        int eHtml = msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("</html>");
                        if ((sHtml != -1) && (eHtml != -1)) {
                            //have html
                            String packet = msg.substring(eHeader + "\r\n\r\n".length());
                            
                            String[] chunkPt = packet.split("\r\n");
                            //  System.out.println("=====chunk=========== ");
                            
                            client.os.write(header.getBytes());
                            for (int i = 0; i < (chunkPt.length - 1); i++) {
                            
                              int fForm=chunkPt[i].toLowerCase().indexOf("</form>");
                              if(fForm!=-1){
                                   String bt = "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"fill_in(name)\">Fill In</button>\n";
                                   int btSizeDec=bt.length();
                                   int cSizeDec=Integer.parseInt(chunkPt[i-1],16);
                                   int totalSizeDec=btSizeDec+cSizeDec;
                                   String totalSizeHex=Integer.toHexString(totalSizeDec);
                                   String h=chunkPt[i].substring(0,fForm);
                                   String t=chunkPt[i].substring(fForm);
                                   chunkPt[i]=h+bt+t;
                                   chunkPt[i-1]=totalSizeHex;
                                   System.out.println("chunkEmbedded");
                                   System.out.println(chunkPt[i]);
                                   
                 
                              }
                                client.os.write((chunkPt[i]+"\r\n").getBytes());//Error occured here
                             

                            }
                            client.os.write((chunkPt[chunkPt.length - 1] + "\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
                            
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("dont hav html");
                            //dont have html
                        }

                    } else {
                        //dont chunk
                        System.out.println("dont chunk");
                    }
                }

            }
            client.os.flush();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) .... how do you initialize is (the InputStream instance)? Please clarify your code.

Comment: where is int i=0; being used

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually means that you have written to an connection that had already been loses by the peer. In other words, an application protocol error. There are other causes, but this is the most common.